# zf2 formFilter regex howto

Tags: zend-framework2, validation

Using zendframework v2, I have run into a problem with a regex validator on a field created by the Form factory. All other fields (using the same pattern) work without a problem.

Any tips, or pointers is appreciated.

```
            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput([ 
            'name' => 'organizationName', 
            'filters' => array( 
                array('name' => 'StripTags'), 
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'), 
            ), 
            'validators' => array( 
                array(
                    'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                    'options' => array(
                        'messages' => array(
                            \Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'Organization name field is empty',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'Regex',
                    'options' => array(
                        'pattern' => '/^[a-z0-9 &-_\.,@]{3,25}$/i',
                        'messages' => array(
                            \Zend\Validator\Regex::INVALID => 'Invalid input, only a-z, 0-9 & - _ . characters allowed',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                array (
                    'name' => 'StringLength', 
                    'options' => array( 
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8', 
                        'min' => '2', 
                        'max' => '25', 
                        'messages' => array(
                            \Zend\Validator\StringLength::TOO_SHORT => 'Organization name field must be at least 8 characters in length',
                            \Zend\Validator\StringLength::TOO_LONG => 'Organization name field must be no longer than 25 characters in length',
                        ),
                    ), 
                ), 
            ), 
        ]));
```

Additional details:
I am using the ZF2 to generate a [form](https://github.com/jas-/myTFH-ZF2/blob/master/vendor/MyTFH/src/MyTFH/Form/RegisterForm.php), I also create a [validation filter](https://github.com/jas-/myTFH-ZF2/blob/master/vendor/MyTFH/src/MyTFH/Form/RegisterValidator.php) and then use the [controller](https://github.com/jas-/myTFH-ZF2/blob/master/vendor/MyTFH/src/MyTFH/Controller/RegisterController.php) to handle proper form submissions.

The problem I am having is with the above inputFilter object that handles the "organizationName" regex filter.

It seems that although the regex patter I use both in the form definition and the input filter of *[a-z0-9 &-_.,@]{3,25}* does not handle the string *Intl. Widgets Inc.* even though I do not get an error message from $form->getMessages() etc.

Color me stumpted

Comment: Would be useful if you could tell us what the problem is exactly.

Comment: I have added some *additional details*

Comment: But the string passes the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your regexp does match `Intl. Widgets Inc.` : http://rubular.com/r/oPbk2cdarB